# How to get SRGP working?

Tags: 10.10, graphics, 64-bit

I'm running 64-bit Ubuntu 10.10, and I'm trying to make SRGP work. SRGP is an old graphics package that accompanies the book "Computer Graphics" by Foley, van Dam, et al.

I have installed libx11-dev, but I still can't get through make.

I get the error "cannot find -lsrgp" when I typed make PROG=show_pattern. Full compilation messages are here http://pastebin.com/CWuw4xte

What do I have to do to get it working?

Comment: The problem isn't that it can't find it, but rather that it's incompatible. Here's the message: `/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible ../lib/libsrgp.a when searching for -lsrgp` The important thing is to figure why libsrgp.a was considered "incompatible".

Comment: I'd check and make sure the architecture of the library is the right one. I'd also try and make most or all of the warnings go away. With old software, you may find it's not compatible with modern software build tools.

Comment: Depending on how old it is, and how tied in with obsolete packages the source is, you might have better luck building it on a virtual machine running an older (and 32-bit) OS.